# Is Azure Load Balancing aware of servers http queue

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, load-balancing

I have some reports that are really heavy. When a given instance starts to process it, it will easily consume 100% of one out of two cores my instance has... if that instance gets 2 of those, for sure it will cause the instance to become unable to handle any other request for aprox 1 min...

I do have other instances running (usually 4-6). Will the load balancer pick on the fact that instance A is clogged and it should not send requests to it while it's under this load? Or no, the load balancer distributes requests evenly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Load Balancer is a TCP & UDP flow based load balancer and does not process application layer traffic.  Load balancing decisions are made per new flow.  Load Balancer uses a hashing function in determining the distribution of new flows.  Distribution mode governs what is taken into account when calculating the hash.

The handshake of your application's client is directly with the VM.  Load Balancer does not have awareness of your HTTP requests and does not queue them.  You need to look at an application layer Load Balancer for such processing, like Azure Application Gateway.  Whether this will solve your scenario isn't clear to me; the fundamental issue seems to be that you do not want to have flows arrive when an instance is busy.

That said, what you can do is use the probe status as a way to signal to Load Balancer that you do not wish to receive more flows. You could use an HTTP probe configuration and have your application signal a probe failure by responding with something other than HTTP 200 and Load Balancer will stop sending new flows to it.  Existing flows load balanced to that instance are not terminated and will continue. You cannot use a probe to discover the load of a virtual machine; Load Balancer cannot see the load of your VM.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of distribution modes you can set on the load balancers, see [Configure the distribution mode for load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-distribution-mode).

From that link you can see there is a degree of stickiness to the system, called a 5-tuple algorithm because it uses 5 attributes: source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port, protocol type.

You can manually switch to 2- or 3-tuple modes using the PowerShell command `Set-AzureLoadBalancedEndpoint ... -LoadBalancerDistribution [opt]`

In the portal I believe this setting is controlled by the "Session Persistence" property in the "Load Balancing Rules" section, but the options are not as fine-grained as can be achieved in PowerShell.

This is not a true round-robin model, as you can see.

You can set the probes to check for live endpoints either by raw TCP (is the port connectable) or by HTTP (can I get a response from the web server), so in your case the best bet is to rely on the HTTP probe to detect that your endpoint is not responding fast enough, and route traffic accordingly.

It's definitely not "aware" of any HTTP queues on the server - don't forget that the load balancer isn't necessarily routing HTTP traffic, and you could be using a wide variety of web servers.  It would be extremely difficult to give the NLB the level of visibility you're talking about in all the possible scenarios.

Comment: does that apply to web apps or only to explicitly created load balancers?

Comment: I'm talking about stand-alone Azure NLBs here; rather than the NLBs used internally by Azure to route traffic between instances of App Services.  There's very little documentation regarding the load distribution between App Service instances, but it's reasonable to expect it to use the same basic principles.

Comment: FWIW @chkuhtz_msft is correct in his response, the attributes I've mentioned actually end up in a hash that allows the NLB to determine the 'appropriate' endpoint.  Azure Application Gateway looks to be loosely based on the IIS ARR (Application Request Routing) module.  ARR can only route on a 'calculated hash' or 'weighted round robin' basis.  It doesn't monitor lag from the origin and route based on node performance.